# Referencing an existing object in PHP... Maybe?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

Here is something I don't understand. I built a pretty cool Router and MCV system based on a video tutorial and it works great! There is one thing I'm a little confused about. It's not anything specific to the code, but more about the logic. In a nutshell:

1. The controller is gotten from the URL
2. The router dispatches the controller class and instantiates it
3. The controller class that gets instantiated extends a base
   controller and will use the corresponding model class

That model class is static and doesn't get instantiated. So, let's say I want to create a new member. From inside the controller class I would have something like:

```
Model::createMember($this->first_name, $this->last_name, $this->screen_name, $this->created_date);
```

Then, of course, in the model I would have a method that creates the member in the underlying database that looks something like:

```
public function createMember($first_name, $last_name, $screen_name, $created_date) { blah blah blah }
```

That is all fine and dandy, but it seems to me I should be able to directly access the properties of the controller object from the model and alleviate from having to pass all those arguments. Accessing properties of an object seems more OOP to me, so that's what I'd like to do.

The problem is, I can't do a

```
$controller_object = new Controller();
```

from within the model class to reference the controller and get access to its properties.

The controller object already exists from the router, so creating a new one does me no good. I need to be able to create a variable that references that existing object.

Right now I have it working, but I basically made the controller object's properties global then could access them directly from the model class with the global keyword, but I don't really want to do it that way.

So is my idea on improving the system just a bad one, or is there a way to reference the existing controller object so I can access it's public properties directly with out having to pass arguments from the controller to the model?

Comment: A model is just a model, it should have no knowledge of your controller or application logic.  If you do, then MVC separation goes away, and your model becomes coupled with and dependent on controller.  The controller should take input and populate the model with it.

Comment: And why access Controller's properties from Model?

Comment: Well, the model is specific to the controller. If I have a MemberController, then I will also have a MemberModel. So, they are related. The MemberModel is basically the CRUD functionality specific to the MemberController, its not just a generic model and it is specific to the controller that will use it.

Comment: I guess the only reason I'm thinking of accessing them directly from the controller object is because it's more object oriented than passing arguments like a procedural function. However, the reality is, there is no real reason other than I am thinking it would be more efficient and cleaner code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is to use `$this`, as it actually represents the instantiated controller when you are inside the controller method, so instead of

```
Model::createMember($this->first_name, $this->last_name, $this->screen_name, $this->created_date);
```

you can just do this

```
Model::createMember($this);
```

And then inside the model you can access the controller object.

Practically, I wouldn't do that as the model actually shouldn't depend on the controller.

Controller responsibility is to parse the incoming request data, create the model and pass the request data into the model.

There is actually no need in having `first_name`, `last_name`, etc properties in the controller. The controller can just have some `$data` array with the incoming data, it should not care about the actual content of this data.

Model responsibility is to validate data (this also can be a separate object) and do the database operations, or any other business logic operations related to the data.

I would also avoid having the static methods for the model. Instead of

```
Model::createMember(...parameters...)
```

I would do

```
// $data is the request data parsed by controller
// controller knows how / where to get the data (from GET, POST, etc)
// but it doesn't care about the actual content
$model = Model($data)
... 
if ($model->validate()) {
    $model->save()
    // show success message to the user
} else {
    // show error message to the user
}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying. Perhaps my system puts a little more weight on the controller. I agree that all database functions are done in the model. However the control needs to know what data it is passing to the model in case it needs to manipulate any data before being passed off to it or when responding to the view.In my case I don't do any server side form validations. All of that is done in the client. The model will check for existing email addresses and matching credentials of course, but no form validations.

Comment: Oh, but anyway, I did change things up some based on comments and I did get rid of all the global variables.